# QPushButton outside windows (inspiration: CleanMyMac)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

[image]I am trying to add a QPushButton in my GUI, such that the pushbutton is party outside the window frame. A good comparison is the `scan` button in CleanMyMac (see attached image).

I have tried making the main window transparent, then adding a background image that is transparent only in the bottom, making the window look smaller than it is. However, this creates a lot of other complications such as window frame shadow (which does not seem to disappear entirely with:

```
mainWindow->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | 
                           Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint)
```

Furthermore, with the mentioned approach, the window cannot be expanded fully, I'd rather have a small part of the button being outside of display (as CleanMyMac).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`QWidget::setMask`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask-1).  By way of an example consider the following class...

```
class widget: public QWidget {
  using super = QWidget;
public:
  explicit widget (QWidget *parent = nullptr)
    : super(parent)
    , m_button("Just hanging here...")
    {
      setLayout(&m_layout);
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_button, 1, 1);
      m_layout.setRowStretch(0, 1);
      m_layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1);
      m_layout.setColumnStretch(2, 1);
    }
protected:
  virtual void resizeEvent (QResizeEvent *event) override
    {
      super::resizeEvent(event);
      QRect r(rect());
      r.setBottom(m_button.geometry().top());
      QRegion region(r);
      region |= m_button.geometry();
      setMask(region);
    }
private:
  QGridLayout m_layout;
  QPushButton m_button;
};
```

The above gives something like...

[image]

Not terribly useful as it stands but it demonstrates the technique.

Comment: How do you put your widget object in the MainWindow, such that its under the window as in your picture? I truly appreciate your help and effort!

Comment: The `widget` class has a [`QGridLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html) and the `QPushButton` is added to that.  So it's a fairly basic widget/layout setup but the parent widget sets its [window mask](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask-1) based on a combination of its own geometry and that of its children -- the `QPushButton`.  Or, perhaps more usefully, try the code both with and *without* the call to [`QWidget::setmask`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask-1) -- that might illustrate things a bit more clearly.

Comment: Right, right. I just noticed is and then saw that you commented ^^ Thanks a lot! Works perfectly! I should be able to work the design out from here.

Answer (score 2):

I'd make the "scan" button a top level widget (i.e. `button->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);` ) make it frameless and borderless, assign a mask to the widget if you want it round and then updating its geometry when the main window moves.

So it's basically 2 windows on top of each other that move together

Comment: I actually tried this as well, but soon realized that the user will have two windows showing in the OS panel as well as two windows when using ctrl+tab, cycling through all windows. This is not a good look. Otherwise it was a simple and neat solution! Or is there perhaps a way to make the system blind towards this second window?